# automatic error reporting - recommendations?

Tags: c++, reporting

Can anyone recommend a library/SDK/etc. that is free or for purchase that I can integrate into my C++ application that enables the application to perform automatic error reporting? I have something now that I am using but it does not catch all exceptions. I'm looking for something more sophisticated and more robust than I have now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention your platform, but if it's Windows, you could take a look at Microsoft's [Windows Error Reporting](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/maintain/StartWER.mspx).

This is the "Application XYZ has crashed. Do you want to send an error report to Microsoft?" stuff. If you sign up for WER, you get access to the error reports (dump files, basically) for your apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *SetUnhandledExceptionFilter* and *MiniDumpWriteDump* functions to make error reporting by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is for Windows, then [XCrashReport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/XCrashReportPt4.aspx) might be an interesting solution. It seems to be small, free, easy to integrate, configure and modify if you need some tweaking.